# Show $au_x+bu_y=f(x,y)$ gives $u(x,y)=(a^2+b^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{L}fds +g(bx-ay)$ if $a\neq 0$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For my homework I am asked to do the following:

Solve $au_x+bu_y=f(x,y)$, where $f(x,y)$ is a given function. If $a\neq 0$ write the solution in the form
$$u(x,y)=(a^2+b^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{L}fds +g(bx-ay)$$
where the integral is a line integral and $L$ is the characteristic line segment from the $y$-axis to the point $(x,y)$ and $g$ is an arbitrary function of one variable. A hint to use the coordinata method (change of coordinates) is given.

For the $g(bx-ay)$ part we have $g_x(bx-ay)=bg'$ and $g_y=-ag'$ so this satisfies $ag_x+bg_y=0$ and therefore is the homogeneous solution. For the rest I realized that $au_x+bu_y$ is the directional derivative of $u$ along the characteristic line $c=bx-ay$ and therefore integrating along this line to solve seems reasonable. However I am unclear about the particulars. If anyone could help me out I would be very thankful. Also, isn't it important that besides specifying $a\neq 0$ we also have $b\neq 0$?

Comment: Are you going to mark your other questions as solved?

Comment: $Kaster I always do, I just have not had the time yet to read the answer thoroughly.

Comment: @Teun Verstraaten:how get $\frac 1{a^2+b^2} \int f (a^2+b^2)^{\frac 12} ds + g(bx - ay)$ from $u = \frac 1{a^2+b^2} \int f dt + g(p)$ i dont know how  change $\int f dt$ to $\int f ds$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, according to my [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304285/solve-au-xbu-ycu-0/304395#304395) answer, if you do transformation
$$
t = bx + ay \\
p = bx - ay
$$
then your equation will be reduced to
$$
2ab\ u_t = f(t,p)
$$
which can be integrated
$$
u(t,p) = \frac 1{2ab} \int f(t,p) dt + g(p)
$$

or alternatively
$$
u(x,y) = \frac 1{2ab} \int f(x,y) (bdx + ady) + g(bx - ay) = \\
 = \frac {(a^2+b^2)^{\frac 12}}{2ab} \int fds + g(bx - ay)
$$

### Update

I indeed made a mistake, but still it isn't the same as your, but it is correct answer though, I just chose different parametrization and consequently characteristics are different. I picked
$$
t = bx + ay\\
p = bx - ay
$$
To get te answer you have, you need to parametrize it as follows:
$$
t = ax + by \\
p = bx - ay
$$
So equations is reduced to
$$
(a^2+b^2) u_t = f \\
u = \frac 1{a^2+b^2} \int f dt + g(p) = \\
= \frac 1{a^2+b^2} \int f (a^2+b^2)^{\frac 12} ds + g(bx - ay) = (a^2+b^2)^{-\frac 12} \int fds + g(bx - ay)
$$
Same parametrization can also be used for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304285/solve-au-xbu-ycu-0/304395#304395) equations. Edits there were made as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am guessing there is a mistake somewhere as the book I am using does not have the extra factor of $2ab$. I will have to go over all the steps in detail before I can understand this answer and hopefully spot the error. Thanks!

Comment: @TeunVerstraaten: There were a mistake, but of a different sense. Fixed it and added new stuff.

Comment: I understand upto the place before using **ds** in last line.But I don't understand how ds is obtained. It was obtained through line integral right?But I don't understand how that line integral was connected to this.I don't have a good knowledge on line integrals. So can someone please explain how **ds** was connected