# Solve the PDE $2U_x -3U_y=x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the PDE

$2U_x -3U_y=x$

$u=u(x,y)$

I wanted to make sure my solution is correct:

characteristic lines: $3x+2y=d$

Change of variables

$w=3x+2y$

$z=y$

The PDE then becomes the ODE:   $V_z= w+2z$

Thus the solution is $u(x,y)= (3x+2y)y + y^2 + C(3x+2y)$

Comment: As a start, the solution you give does not satisfy the differential equation (you will find $2U_x-3U_y = -12y - 9x\ne x$).

Comment: Try [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304321/show-au-xbu-y-fx-y-gives-ux-y-a2b2-frac12-int-lfds-gbx/305075#305075) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [method of characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). Here is the final answer

$$ u \left( x,y \right) =\frac{1}{4}\,{x}^{2}+{F} \left( y+\frac{3}{2}\,x \right).  $$

Answer (score 0):

Simply use method of characteristics.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I would recommend adding more details to your answer as it may not be clear to the OP. Regards